# Does a MIUI-Phone work in Europe?

Tags: hardware, miui

I've just read about the chinese MIUI Phones ([Mi Two](http://phandroid.com/2012/08/16/xiaomi-announces-mi-two-jelly-bean-s4-pro-quad-core-processor-2gb-ram-and-miui-custom-ui-for-only-315/)), my question is wheter they work in Europe, or might there be some issues because of other phone networks? Might there be some other issues apart from that?

Bonus Question: Does the official MIUI-Rom has any other languages than Chinese?

Comment: China uses a variant of CDMA type of radio baseband IIRC (definitely not GSM that's for sure) Last I heard there was a MIUI distributor based in Germany.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to GSMArena, the Xiaomi Mi-Two supports the following frequencies:

2G Network: GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900

3G Network: HSDPA 850 / 1900 / 2100

You can check what frequencies your country uses [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/network-bands.php3). It should work in most if not all EU countries though.

Also, it supports Chinese and English officially but there is unofficial support for other languages, located [here](http://en.miui.com/download.html).